# NatTable HoverStylingCommandHandler not being triggered by HoverStylingCommand

Tags: nattable

The issue that I am having is that I am attempting to execute a HoverStylingCommand by calling:

```
natTable.doCommand(new HoverStylingCommand(natTable, columnIndex, rowIndex, hoverLayer);
```

and the HoverStylingCommandHandler that is registered by the HoverLayer is never being triggered when the command is executed. However the handler does get hit when the exact same command is triggered from the SimpleHoverStylingBinding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to execute the HoverStylingCommand programmatically. It is intended to operate in combination with the mouse cursor position. IIRC the command handler performs a check on the mouse cursor position. So from the functional point of view it is correct that the command handler is not triggered.